# how to prevent logging warrning in webpack

Tags: webpack-dev-server, generator-react-webpack

I am using [this generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-react-webpack) to build react application. All the warnings listing in console; Its messing console all and very annoying

[image]

how can I turn it off ? I checked webpack.config file but cant see any info about it

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are a result of the generator's [eslint configuration](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring). To change the config project-wide look for the `.eslintrc` file in the project's root directory. To stop reporting unused variables e.g., add a line with `"no-unused-vars": 0` to the config.

To read up on the eslint rules and how to configure them it is best to look them up on their website, e.g.

- [no-unused-vars](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)
- [quotes](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes)
- [no-undef](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)
- [comma-dangle](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle)
- [no-console](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console)
- [no-trailing-spaces](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-trailing-spaces)

Comment: Understood, but I want it show these warnings in cmd thats fine, but I dont want to see them in browser's console

Comment: @TyForHelpDude that's a good question, hope to find a bit of time tonight to check if/how this is possible. that said, from my experience it's worth picking the rules one wishes to follow and fix violations as early as possible. but devs may choose other workflows.